# KendoUI numerictextbox format doesn't work using angularJS directives

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui

I have a KendoUI numerictextbox in my page. When I use it withou AngularJS directives, it works fine.

```
<input id="currency" type="number" value="30" min="0" max="100" />


$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#currency").kendoNumericTextBox({
    format: "R$ #",
    decimals: 0
    });
});
```

When I change the component atributes to accept AngularJS directives, the format stops working:

```
<input id="currency" name="currency" kendo-numeric-text-box k-value="30" k-min="0" k-max="100" />

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#currency").kendoNumericTextBox({
    format: "R$ #",
    decimals: 0
    });
});
```

There is something needed to do this work (format) when using AngularJS directives?

Regards.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should not use the jQuery kendo directive calls when using the angular-kendo directives. Hence, your jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#currency").kendoNumericTextBox({
    format: "R$ #",
    decimals: 0
    });
});
```

should be removed.

Instead, you should set the options either directly in the view or set the options use "k-options" and bind it to a scope variable.

For reference, here's the code you should use:

```
<input id="currency" name="currency" kendo-numeric-text-box k-options="options" k-ng-model="val" k-value="30" k-min="0" k-max="100" />
```

And in your controller/directive you should set the model for the options and the value variable:

```
$scope.options = {
          format: "R$ #",
                decimals: 0
        }
```

Here's a working example with your set of options:
http://dojo.telerik.com/oKIJ

Comment: Why won't the k-decimals attribute work? According to their documentation it should work, the k-min and k-max work in this example.  Also in your Dojo if you remove the format option the decimals option doesn't work. I don't think Telerik has hooked up all the options, how sloppy on their part.

Comment: @ScottWilson - I could only get it to work by using the format "c2" (currency 2 decimals) and not setting the decimal property.  It appears that you can either use decimal OR format but not both.